# Unable to publish Smartface 4.4.04 project

Tags: smartface.io

I am using jdk1.8.0_05 and unable to publish the project to Android. I am getting message 'Need 1.7 jdk'. Should I downgrade my jdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also don't forget to check (if you've already set the path to the jdk 1.7) if your path go into the "bin" folder like "jdk1.7blabla/bin" and not only "jdk1.7blabla".

I solved the same problem with this solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jdk1.7.0_71 in order to get Android publish with the existing setup of Smartface which is 4.4.0.

Also you should check this document about configuration : 
http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/get-started/configuration/#conf-java